# ios ad-hoc in-app purchase: is it normal that asking user credential only once while user buys multiple items?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, itunes

I am testing IAP on ad-hoc build version.

when I buy an app item first time, apple asks my apple id(I am using testing account) and password.

But when I try to buy other items after fist purchase, apple does not ask my credential and take care

IAP process automatically. I am not sure this is normal behavior or not.

I thought apple would ask my credential every time I try to buy app items.

I am confused. is it normal that apple skip authentication after first authentication?

or am I missing something?

Comment: If the purchases are done within a limited time of one another, this is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple only revalidates Apple Ids after I believe 15 minutes. So the first purchase validates the ID and subsequent purchases are run without revalidating. To test this space out your second purchase 15 minutes. You should be asked for the into again.

Apple Does this so you don't have to put in your password everytime. The assumption is someone didn't steal your phone within 15 minutes of you purchasing something. Try this with app store. Download an app and notice subsequent downloads within 15 minutes don't require entering your apple ID.

Answer: Yes it totally normal